# Display column based on certain condition

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to display column based on certain condition, is it possible for that as i do this getting an error.

```
    select (
              select column_name 
              from all_tab_cols
              where table_name='BED_2016_MAR_CIT4114A_FYP1_G_' 
                    and column_name like '%na%'
           )
    from BED_2016_MAR_CIT4114A_FYP1_G_;
```

Comment: What error? Presumably not "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" which is what I get...  But if I use a table that does exist in my schema instead of BED_2016_MAR_CIT4114A_FYP1_G_ then I get no error at all.

Comment: the error is logic error nothing displaying. I basically want like it selects columns based on condition like usually we put select * or select id, name, so i want like select based on the columns which have like %na%

Comment: The column *name* is like `na` (in lower case, implying quoted identifiers); or the column value is like `na`? They are very different things. Are you trying to identify which columns contain data matching that pattern?

Comment: i tried still not working. I want to display column which have that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query must list the columns it is using explicitly.  You can do what you want using dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`).  For example:

```
declare
    sql varchar2(4000);
    cols varchar2(4000);
begin
    select listagg(column_name, ',') within group (order by column_name)
    into cols
    from all_tab_cols
    where table_name = 'BED_2016_MAR_CIT4114A_FYP1_G_' and column_name like '%na%' ;

    sql := '
create table newtab as
select @cols
from BED_2016_MAR_CIT4114A_FYP1_G_';

    sql := replace(sql, '@cols', cols);

    execute immediate sql;
end;

select * 
from newtab;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in the `where` condition:

```
where table_name='BED_2016_MAR_CIT4114A_FYP1_G_' 
                    and column_name like '%na%'
```

Remove the condition for table_name. You are already selecting from BED_2016_MAR_CIT4114A_FYP1_G_ so only columns in that table will be shown.

Here is a more simplified version of the query:

```
select column_name 
from BED_2016_MAR_CIT4114A_FYP1_G_
where column_name like '%na%'
```

Hope that helped